# How to add multiple images in an Image view which is included in a layout?

Tags: android

I'm working with a project in which I have a layout with a button "Add photo", an Image View allowing to add multiple images from SD card whenever I press button "Add photo"? Can you give me some guides with this project. I'm new to android so every help is appreciated :). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create  a GridView for showing all images when ever user clicks add image  to the data in adapter and refresh it 
please refer to this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/)